# Getting value with Jquery in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have tried many things but without success.

I want to get the value introduced by the user (user_entry) when clicking on the button (ddd).

This is what I have:

My `index.html.erb`

```
<div >
  <p class="mod1_title">Intro</p>
  <div class="mod1_boxed">
    <strong>Jahreshausverbrauch (kWh):</strong>
      <%= form_tag( '/welcome/index', post: true ) do %>
      <%= text_field_tag "module1", nil, placeholder: "Bsp. 3500", id: "user_entry" %></br>

      <strong>PV-Große (kWp):</strong></br>
      <%= text_field_tag "module2", nil, placeholder: "Bsp. 5", id: "user_entry_2" %></br>
      <%= submit_tag "send", id: "ddd" %>

      <%end%>
  </div>  
</div>


<script >

$(function(){


        $("#ddd").change(function(){ 
        var number_value =  $(this).val("#user_entry_module1"); 
         console.log(number_value); 
         });
});

</script>
```

Any idea?

Comment: [jQuery's `val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) either returns the value of the first matched elements, or sets it to the given one. I have a feeling you want neither.

Comment: I want both, I was just trying to understand with a simple example (getting only one value).

Comment: Uhm, sorry, I misspoke -- you **do** neither: you currently set all the matched elements' values to `#user_entry_model`. And, of this I'm certain now, it's not your goal. Your usage of `val` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use click event on button instead of change event,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#ddd").click(function(){ 
       var number_value =  $("#user_entry").val(); 
       console.log(number_value); 
     });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: I changed console.log by alert and it shows: [object Object]

Comment: What are you getting in `$("#user_entry").val()` ?

Comment: Why are you passing `nil` in `<%= text_field_tag "module1", nil, placeholder: "Bsp. 3500", id: "user_entry" %>` ?

Comment: Otherwise I get in that field: {:placeholder=>"Bsp. 3500", :id=>"user_entry"}

Comment: It did not work unfortunately in that way, the output is always [object Object]. But I found another way how to do it. I don't know if I should put it as a new answer or update my original question.

Comment: If it isn't much of a change then u can edit the given answers and accept that as correct

Answer (score 0):

*Use*

```
//Its button so use click event
$("#ddd").click(function(){

    //Id is user_entry not user_entry_module1
    //You need id selector to find element the use .val() method to read its value
    var number_value =  $("#user_entry").val(); 

    console.log(number_value); 
});
```

References:

- [ID Selector (“#id”)](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

> Selects a single element with the given id attribute.

- [`$.fn.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val1)

> Description: Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements.

---

Use

```
$("form").submit(function(){

    //Id is user_entry not user_entry_module1
    //You need id selector to find element the use .val() method to read its value
    var number_value =  $("#user_entry").val(); 

    console.log(number_value); 
});
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried like this but in my console log does not show the value introduced.

Comment: @kaka, Try with `button_tag` once and check are you getting error in console, Can you post generated HTML also http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: Oh, You are using `form_tag` it creates the form and post data thats why you are not able see the data I have updated answer

Comment: I changed to button_tag. It shows no errors in the console